# How is the park rating calculated?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

In Rollercoaster Tycoon 2 there is a park rating system from 1 - 999 which basically says how good your park is. I've noticed that a large amount of guest complaints lowers it, while good rides with a high satisfaction increase it. However, I'd like to know how it's calculated mathematically and was unable to find anything on Google.

**How is the ingame park rating system calculated?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some more concrete details from an analysis of the reverse-engineered Roller Coaster Tycoon 2 source code, provided and maintained by the [OpenRCT2](https://openrct2.website/) project.

Roller Coaster Tycoon 2 calculates a park's rating perhaps in reverse from how you'd expect;  it starts you out with full points, and then deducts points for things that are wrong with the park.

Or actually, it starts you with *more* than full points, so you can have a couple of problems before they begin to noticeably affect your park rating.

You start with a value of 1150 (or 1050, in 'difficult' scenarios).  And then:

- Number of guests in the park (0-2000) adds -150 to +3.
- Percentage of guests in the park that are at least 50% happy (0%-83%) adds -500 to +0
- Each guest who is currently lost (excluding the first 25) adds -7.
- If there are no rides or facilities in the park, add -200.
- If there *are* rides or facilities in the park, then average recent downtime across everything in the park (0%-100%) adds +0 to -200.
- If there are no rides, add -100.
- If there *are* rides, take the difference between the average ride excitement value and 3.6.  As this difference goes (0-4.0), add +0 to -50.
- If there *are* rides, take the difference between the average ride intensity value and 5.2.  As this difference goes (0-4.0), add +0 to -50.
- Total ride intensity value across all rides (0-40.0) adds -100 to +0.
- Total ride excitement value across all rides (0-40.0) adds -100 to +0.
- Pieces of litter in the park (0-150) adds +0 to -600.
- Number of fatalities ever in the park (0-3) adds -0 to -600.
- Finally, clamp the resulting value into the range (0-999).

That's it!  That's the complete calculation for park rating.  It's calculated from scratch every time it updates, which is once every 512 game ticks (approximately 5 seconds).

Notes:

Where I list a range of input values and what they add, the mapping between the range of values and the bonus/penalty points they award is linear.  If you have 1000 guests in the park (halfway between 0 and 2000), you get -73 points added to your park rating (halfway between -150 and +3).

Where I've listed a range of input values, values outside the range are clamped into it.  So for example, there is no further benefit to park rating for having more than 2000 guests in the park;  if you have 3000 guests, they'll be treated as if there were only 2000 for the purposes of this calculation.

The penalty to Park Rating for fatalities in the park appears to be permanent;  I can't find anything in the code which ever reduces it.  (Peeps will eventually stop worrying about a ride which they think of as unsafe if it runs for a long time without accidents afterwards, but the park rating will never recover)

A couple of surprises, here:

- Scenery doesn't matter at all (except inasmuch as it affects the excitement level of rides).
- Variety of stalls/rides doesn't matter at all (having multiple rides of the same type does reduce their ride value, and ride value affects the park value and a bunch of other things, but it *doesn't* affect the park *rating*.)
- Prices for stalls/rides don't matter at all.
- Awards don't matter at all.

Comment: A very detailed and interesting answer. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: An extra side-note:  Park rating only has two actual functions in the game (ignoring scenarios which use it as an objective):  It has a moderate effect on how frequently new park guests are generated (this benefit tops out at a rating of 850), and if its value is > 650, then it blocks your park from receiving the "Most Disappointing Park" award, even if your rides are all very disappointing.  Otherwise, it's completely unused by the game.

Answer (score 1):

While it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out the particular equation used to calculate the park rating, the following things all affect your park's rating (this list is from the [Roller Coaster Tycoon Wiki](http://rct.wikia.com/wiki/Park_Rating):

- Variety of Rides
- Amount of Rides
- Quality of Rides
- Variety of Stalls
- Amount of Stalls
- Scenery
- Vandalism
- Cleanliness of Footpaths
- Safety
- Happiness of guests
- Lost Guests
- Prices for rides and stalls
- Awards

So basically, the answer is that *everything* affects the park's rating. As I stated before though, it is unlikely that we will ever know the exact math behind the rating.

Comment: Do you know if any of those factors are more important than the others, or are they all of equal importance?

Comment: I don't know for certain, and I haven't been able to find anywhere that states if any are more important than the others. From my personal experience, I think that the variety and quality of rides is a huge factor though, along with happiness of guests. It's hard to say, since things like "Happiness of guests" entails a lot of the other things (prices, quality of rides, cleanliness, stalls, scenery, etc).